# Error System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] when itry String.Join on a list of result

Tags: c#, list

I am getting the error System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] when i try to use String.Join in a list of result.

For instance i have two list like this:

```
var list1= new List<string>{"string1","string2"};
var list2= new List<string>{"string1"};
```

Then i want to get a message with the string that doesn't appear on list2

```
var resultList1 = list1.Except(list2).ToList(); // this line get a list with "string2"
```

when i use String.Join i get the error System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].  Also i tried resultList1.Cast<List>() instead resultList1 with same outcome.

```
var message = "List strings not found:\n\n"
                + String.Join(",", $"\n\n{resultList1}\n\n");
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the error _message_ is, but my best guess is that the second parameter of `string.Join()` needs to be a collection.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and learn to use [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the string join like ths,

```
var message = "List strings not found:\n\n" + String.Join(",", resultList1);
```

You are using the system join on an enumerable array but when you use $"\n\n{result1}\n\n" string interpolation, you are basically joining a single string which doesn't work.

String.Join takes in a string (comma, newline or any string)  that combines all elements from an array but when you give string instead of array or collection, it will give the error.

Lastly, [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) should help explain more about the usage in depth.

Comment: Thanks for you asnwer. It was really helpful to me

Comment: @Andres if the post answered your question, please be sure to mark it as answered by clicking the ✔ under the vote count